# Get specific information depends user logged in jquery mobile

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, mysqli

I'm developing a jquery mobile app that uses php to get information from the database ( e.g user login ). but I've this problem: I need to display specific information from the database depends on the user logged ( clients and proyects are related one each other by 'project' field in clients and 'id' in projects )

I was trying to add the field 'project' into the 'login' query but when I made this the app couldn't logged

Thanks in advance for your help

----------- index.html --------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/surinteractive.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theme/css/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.3/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/json.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="a">
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Sistema de gesti&oacute;n de Requerimientos</h1>
</header>  
<div data-role="content">
    <div id="fm">
        <form id="form">
            <label for="username">User:</label>
            <input type="text" value="" name="username" id="username"/>
            <label for="password">Pass:</label>
            <input type="password" value="" name="password" id="password"/>  
            <a data-role="button" id="login-button" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn-icon-right ui-icon-plus ui-btn-b">
                Sign in
            </a>
        </form>       
    </div>
</div>    
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2014 </p>
</footer>   
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="menu" data-theme="a">
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href="#login" data-transition="slide" data-role="button" class="b_nuevo">Back</a>
            <h3>Bugs List</h3>
</header>
<div data-role="content">
    <h3>Welcome: </h3>
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
         <li><a href="bugs/errors.html" data-transition="slide">Create a bug</a></li>
         <li><a href="enh/enhacements.html" data-transition="slide">Create an enhacement</a></li>
    </ul>      
</div>
<footer data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2014</p>
</footer>
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

------------------ json.js --------------------------

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#login', function(){ 


$('#login-button').on('click', function(){


    if($('#username').val().length > 0 && $('#password').val().length > 0){


        userObject.username = $('#username').val(); 
        userObject.password = $('#password').val();


        var outputJSON = JSON.stringify(userObject);


        ajax.sendRequest({action : 'login', outputJSON : outputJSON});

    } else {

        alert('Please fill all requested information');

    }
});    
});


var ajax = {

sendRequest:function(save_data){

    var address = null;

    //address = 'http://127.0.0.1/app/inc/userValidation.php?jsoncallback=?';

    $.ajax({url: address,
        crossDomain: true,
        data: save_data,
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
            $.mobile.loading('show', {theme:"a", text:"Initializing...", textonly:true, textVisible: true});
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
            $.mobile.loading('hide');
        },
        success: function (result) {
            if(result == "true") {
                $.mobile.changePage( "#menu", { transition: "slide"} ); 



            } else {
                alert('Invalid login. Please try again!'); // In case result is false throw an error
            }
            // This callback function will trigger on successful action
        },
        error: function (request,error) {

            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
            alert('Connection error, please try again');

        }
    });
}
```

}

```
// We will use this object to store username and password before we serialize it and send to     server. This part can be done in numerous ways but I like this approach because it is simple
var userObject = {
username : "",
password : ""
}
```

------------ userValidation.php -------------------

```
<?php

$jsonObject = json_decode($_REQUEST['outputJSON']); // Decode JSON object into readable PHP object

$username = $jsonObject->{'username'}; // Get username from object
$password = $jsonObject->{'password'}; // Get password from object

$connection = null;


$connection = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx'); 


$query = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE username = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$num = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);

if($num != 0) {
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";        
}
?>
```

---

Database ( Structure & Relationship )

**clients**
id, name, username, password, projectid, status, creation_date

**projects**
id, project, description, technologies, status, creation_date

**bugs**
id name projectid, type, environment,description, status, creation_date

projectid.clients = id.projects

id.projects = projectid.bugs

**Objective: Store the username in a global variable to be recovered in another page**

Comment: I add a typical user log in but the problem is how can I do to keep the projectid from client table in the other pages to use it in the query to list the specific bugs created by this user linked to his own project....  e.g  ( user csheen / projectid: 1 / bugs created before for the project 1: 10 ) ... user:rgiggs / projectid: 2 / / bugs created before for the project 2: 4 )

Comment: So, your problem is SQL query? Do I understand this correctly? You are validating username and password against `clients` table, if result is not 0 - true, else false. You need to JOIN `projects` ON `clients.projectid = projects.id` to get user projects, but where do you keep record of the bugs? Show your schema.

Comment: To keep the projectid after you retrieve it, store in php session, browser localStorage/sessionStorage, cookie

Comment: I added the bugs schema structure.

Comment: The issue is in the whole procedure because when I modified the SQL to get the projectid from the client schema and the added a global php variable to store this, the application did not sign it anymore

Comment: Show your modified query

Comment: I am Not sure you can log in at all,mysqli affected rows -Returns the number of rows affected by the last INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query.you should use `mysqli_num_rows` instead.

Comment: I need to use this: $('#bugs').live('pageshow', function(event) {
 var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
 $.getJSON('buglist.php?id='+id, displayEmployee);
});

function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}

The idea is to keep the id from the user logged, store it in a global variable or something similar and get the id in another page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've solved this issue creating a new schema called sessions, when the user signs it to the app, it will be store in that schema. After this, if the user wants to get the list of bugs created a new sql sentence will be called to join 'sessions' in that search